# Incomplete block design analysis

Tags: generalized-linear-model, normality-assumption, count-data, negative-binomial-distribution, blocking

I have 4 treatments (6m, 12m, 24m, 40m) in 3 blocks, but all treatments are not replicated in these blocks: 6m, 12m, 24m are in Blk1 and Blk2 and Blk3 consist of only 34m (control plot) and 6m.

1. How do I check for distribution normality? Should it be individual
   treatment or together?
2. What is best way to analyse such data using GLMs (negative binomial)?

The data is count data (number of insects) collected over time.

Answer (score 1):

Your Q1: You have count data, and say you want a negative binomial model, so there is no assumption of normality, no normality testing is required. As your design is connected, there should be no problems with identification, see [Examples of connected designs in DOE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/266944/examples-of-connected-designs-in-doe).

Blocks are often treated as random effects, and so a mixed model framework is used. But with only three blocks I am not sure if that is necessary, so will answer using glm's. The simplest model with count data is Poisson (with log link function.) Writing `y` for the count response, `bl` the blocking factor and `tr` the treatment factor, you would use `constant+bl+bl` for the linear predictor.

In `R` the model could be specified as

```r
mod1  <-  glm(y ~ bl+tr, data=yourdataframe, family=poisson, ...)
```

or for a quasipoisson family change to `family=quasipoisson`. For a negative binomial model

```r
library(MASS)
mod2  <-  glm.nb(y ~ bl+tr, data=yourdataframe, ...)
```