# Does a balanced design have to be connected?

Tags: estimation, experiment-design, contrasts, treatment-effect, efficiency

Under a general block design setup, consider $v$ treatments allocated to $b$ blocks. Let $r_i$ and $k_j$ be the replication number of the $i$th treatment and $j$ the block respectively. We define $n_{ij}$ as the number of times the $i$th treatment appears in the $j$th block, $i=1,\ldots,v;j=1,\ldots,b$ and construct the incidence matrix $N=(n_{ij})_{v\times b}$. Let $R=\operatorname{diag}(r_1,r_2,\ldots,r_v)$ and $K=\operatorname{diag}(k_1,k_2,\ldots,k_b)$.

Then characteristic matrix of the block design corresponding to treatment effects is given by $C=R-NK^{-1}N'$.

Some relevant definitions and results from *Theory of Block Designs* by Aloke Dey:

> A block design is ***connected*** if all elementary treatment contrasts are estimable.

Alternative definition due to R.C. Bose:

> A treatment $i$ and a block $j$ in a block design are said to be *associated* if the treatment $i$ appears in the block $j$. Two treatments are said to be connected if it is possible to pass from one to the other through a chain consisting alternatively of treatments and blocks such that any two members of a chain are associated. A design is ***connected*** if every pair of treatments is connected.

- A block design is connected if and only if $\operatorname{rank}(C)=v-1$.

> A block design is ***(variance) balanced*** if it permits the estimation of all estimable normalized treatment contrasts with the same variance.

- A *connected* block design is balanced if and only if all non-zero eigenvalues of $C$ are equal.
- A *connected* block design is balanced if and only if $C$ can be written as $C=(a-b)I_v+b\mathbf1_v\mathbf1_v'$ for some scalars $a,b$.

**But how to verify if a design is variance-balanced when it is *not* connected? Is a balanced design always assumed to be connected?**

---

Consider this worked out example from the book *Experimental Designs: Exercises and Solutions* by Gupta and Kabe:

[image]

They have stated that the theorem on eigenvalues of $C$ holds for any design (connected or not) and hence came to this conclusion. But this does not seem to complement the actual theorem. If a balanced design has to be connected, this answer cannot be right.

Can I answer whether the design in this example is balanced or not straight from definition?

Comment: Nothing is mentioned about unbiasedness. Basically I get conflicting answers from different sources, hence the question.

Comment: That reference you have included now is clearly **wrong**. Write its authors!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Summary:  Yes, a balanced block design have to be connected**.

You say you get different answers from different sources. If we are to discuss this, you must give references to those different sources with conflicting answers! Your reference is *Theory of Block Designs* by Aloke Dey. I do not have access to that, but to the newer *INCOMPLETE BLOCK DESIGNS* [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/9814322687) by the same author, which seem to have been written as a modernized replacement.

The reason for the answer is almost by definition: For a design to be balanced, first, all contrasts must be *estimable*, and that is basically the definition of *connected*. Below a short summary, with some definitions.

Notation is the same as used in the question.

**Definition 2.2.2** A block design is said to be **connected** if all treatment contrasts are estimable.  This is in fact equivalent to the graph theory definition used in [Examples of connected designs in DOE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/266944/examples-of-connected-designs-in-doe/268530#268530).  This is discussed (among other things) in the very interesting paper at [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1111.3768.pdf).

**Definition of *estimable contrast** (not given in that book, assumed) A contrast  $l^T\theta$ with $l\not= 0$ is *estimable* if an unbiased estimator of it exists.

**Lemma 2.2.4** A linear parametric function $p^T \tau$ (with $p\not= 0$) is estimable for a block design $d$ iff $p\in \mathcal{C}(C)$, that is, $p$ is in the column space of the designs C-matrix.

**Theorem 2.2.1** A block design with $\nu$ treatments is connected iff (if and only if) $\DeclareMathOperator{\Rank}{Rank}   \Rank(C)=\nu-1$, where $C$ is its C-matrix or characteristic matrix.

**Definition 2.3.1** A connected block design is said to be variance-balanced if it permits the estimation of every normalized treatment contrast with the same variance.   So we can see that the conclusion is built into the definition, but even without that, the result is clear, since the requirement *to be estimable with the same variance* obviously presupposes to be *estimable*.

Then there is the concept of *efficiency balance*, where much the same can be repeated.

---

**Your example** is $b=2$ blocks with $\nu=4$ treatments, block 1 with treatments 1,4 and block 2 with treatments 2,3. Write the treatment effects as $\tau_1,\tau_2,\tau_3, \tau_4$. Then, for example, the treatment contrast $\tau_2 -\tau_1$ is not estimable, so the design is not connected.  You can write out a linear model with a general mean, treatment effects and block effects, and see what happens.  We can also use lemma 2.2.4 above. $\tau_2-\tau_1 = p^T\tau$ with $p=(-1,1,0,0)^T$. The C-matrix of the design is 
$$
  C=\frac12\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0& 0& -1 \\
                           0&1&-1&0\\
                           0&-1&1&0\\
                           -1&0&0&1
   \end{pmatrix}
$$  and it is clear that $p$ cannot be written as a linear combination of the columns of $C$.

But the intuitive idea of estimation of treatment contrasts in block designs, **is to use really only within-block contrasts**, and so average them. That is called the *intra-block* analysis. In the example, there is no blocks where both treatments 1 and 2 are used, so no within-block contrasts.

Comment: I think you are right. In any case I have highlighted the confusion in my edit.

Comment: Do you still have doubts or questions? if not, maybe accept/upvote?

Comment: Sorry about that.

Comment: I looked at another book that has a section titled *Balancing in connected and disconnected designs* where it is stated that the theorem on eigenvalues is true for any design. The theorem due to Rao I cited in my post is stated to be true for connected designs, whereas the corresponding result for any design analogous to this theorem is left as an exercise.

Comment: Can you tell us which book, and cite the theorem?

Comment: I would do that later; the theorem is exactly as stated in Aloke Dey's book. A problem with these references on design of experiments is that online pdf copies are not available.

Comment: ... but that will not change my conclusion, a disconnected design cannot be balanced, period. The concept of balance do not make much sense for disconnected designs, and disconected designs do not have much interest anyway. I would caution against putting to much interest in them!