# Analysis of variance in a multi-site agricultural field experiment?

Tags: anova, experiment-design

I have a dataset on the yield of rice collected from 17 different sites where 3 different fertilizer management methods were tested.

However, there were three different rice varieties tested in an unequal number of sites, for example, Variety 1, 2, and 3 were tested in two, six, and nine sites, respectively. When I had conducted ANOVA of the effect of sites (17) (across varieties and treatments), treatments (3) (across sites and varieties), and varieties (across sites and treatments) I could get the results clearly.

But when I run the GLM, the varieties were excluded from the analysis and the remaining factors only were analyzed. I understand that this could be because of a lack of balance. However, the data needs analysis and I seek a solution from the forum. Suggest a software also.

Comment: If you want good feedback, a reproducible example would be very helpful.  This doesn't have to use your actual data (if it's private), but instead use simulated data.  See this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: This is difficult to answer without more details, especially the software you used and sample sizes. But, as a guess, your design might not be connected:  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/266944/examples-of-connected-designs-in-doe/268530#268530